# how to pass the count of related model class to view page in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i have created 2 model classes Mocmodel and mocsubmodel and set navigation property also.for each model id, there will be different submodels for a particular model id. i wanted to create am action link showing count of submodels, when i click on the count, view should display submodel details for each particular modelIDs like below

1220 FXRate count as hyperlink

```
 public class tModel
{
    public int ModelID { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; } 
     public virtual ICollection<tSubModelcs> submodellist { get; set; }

} 

public class tSubModelcs
{
    public int submodelID { get; set; }
    public string submodel { get; set; }
    public DateTime launchdate { get; set; }

    public int ModelID { get; set; }
}
```

in my view page i want to display the count of submodel as a link

```
  @foreach (var m in Model)
   {
   <tr>
   <td>@m.ModelID</td>
   <td>@m.ModelName</td>

    <td>
    Html.ActionLink(, "findsubmodels", new { @id = m.ModelID, @class =  "linkclick" })
     </td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is clear.  Which model are you sending to view ? Post your complete code with action methods. It seems like you are sending IEnumerable of tModel. If this is the case your Actionlink should be like this.

```
@if(m.submodellist != null)
{
   @Html.ActionLink(m.submodellist.Count.ToString(), "findsubmodels",null, new { id = @m.ModelID, @class = "linkclick" })
}
```

Replace the null with your routevalue if any.